# Hash using a key in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to create a hash in Powershell using a key but I seemed to be getting a different result compared when I'm doing it with Python.

Its a signature that I'm generating for an API call.

The Python code I use is as follows:

```
nonce         = "20"
client_id     = "mdfgfgkjl3456"
api_key       = "asdkjasdkljsomekey"
message       = nonce + client_id + api_key
secret        = "dsdklfjsdfkljsomesecret"
secret_bytes  = bytes(secret , 'latin-1')
message_bytes = bytes(message , 'latin-1')

signature = hmac.new(
    secret_bytes,
    msg=message_bytes,
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest().upper()
```

The Powershell Code that I have is as follows:

```
$nonce    = "20"
$clientid = "mdfgfgkjl3456"
$apikey   = "asdkjasdkljsomekey"
$message  = $nonce + $clientid + $apikey
$secret   = "dsdklfjsdfkljsomesecret"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
        $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
        $signature = 
$hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
        $signature = ([Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)).ToUpper()
        $signature
```

The Powershell runs but it produces a different Signature then the Python code.

Comment: This is because the default character encoding for Python is UTF-8 (I believe) whereas the default character encoding for Powershell is UTF-16

Comment: Thanks Bryce I've changed to UTF8 for both Text.Encoding like below but I'm still not getting the correct result:

`([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($message))`

Comment: It may be wise to figure out what text encoding your python instance is using.  If it's using something odd, you'll need to make powershell use the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PowerShell version you perform an additional operation - converting the byte array to a Base64 string - before converting it to upper case:

```
$signature = ([Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)).ToUpper()
```

Python on  the other hand converts the array to a hexadecimal string.

Change the powershell version to:

```
$nonce    = "20"
$clientid = "mdfgfgkjl3456"
$apikey   = "asdkjasdkljsomekey"
$message  = $nonce + $clientid + $apikey
$secret   = "dsdklfjsdfkljsomesecret"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = -join($signature |ForEach-Object ToString X2).ToUpper()
$signature
```

`-join($signature |ForEach-Object ToString X2).ToUpper()` will produce the exact same format as `.hexdigest().upper()`